# Nested Dealer::Card::Deck class Deck.cards gets the list during the build method, but list is gone during shuffle method

Tags: class, nested, attributes, python-3.8, nonetype

I've simplified the code a bit as it is a part of larger flask project. But the problem is still present here:

```
import random
class Dealer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = self.Deck()
    class Deck:
        def __init__(self):
            self.cards = []
            self.cards = self.build()
        def build(self):
            for suit in ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']:
                if suit == 'Spades':
                    suit_url='S.png'
                elif suit == 'Diamonds':
                    suit_url="D.png"
                elif suit == "Hearts":
                    suit_url="H.png"
                elif suit == "Clubs":
                    suit_url="C.png"
                for val in [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]:
                    img_url = (str(val) + suit_url)
                    self.cards.append(self.Card(val, suit, img_url))
        def shuffle(self):
            for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
                rand_num = random.randint(0, i)
                self.cards[i], self.cards[rand_num] = self.cards[rand_num], self.cards[i]
        class Card:
            def __init__(self, value, suit, img):
                self.value = value
                self.suit = suit
                self.img = img                
dealer = Dealer()
deck = dealer.Deck()
deck.shuffle()
```

cards list shows a valid list of card objects in the Deck build method, but when it gets to the shuffle method cards shows none in debugger?

Comment: I've tried moving the deck and nested card class outside the Dealer class and them pass the deck, but the '''deck.cards''' still comes back as none. Not sure what I'm doing wrong the cards prop is iterable inside the Deck, but not after the build method has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong:

'self.build()' Method doesn't return anything (VOID) it's only update the 'self.cards'. But 'self.cards' seated equiel to the output of 'self.build()'.
But the output is none, and when you want to use 'deck.shuffle()' you are trying to get the length of none.

How to fix:

Just call build method to fill the cards.

```
import random
class Dealer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = self.Deck()
    class Deck:
        def __init__(self):
            self.cards = []
            # Just call build method to fill the cards
            self.build()
        def build(self):
            for suit in ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']:
                if suit == 'Spades':
                    suit_url='S.png'
                elif suit == 'Diamonds':
                    suit_url="D.png"
                elif suit == "Hearts":
                    suit_url="H.png"
                elif suit == "Clubs":
                    suit_url="C.png"
                for val in [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]:
                    img_url = (str(val) + suit_url)
                    self.cards.append(self.Card(val, suit, img_url))
        def shuffle(self):
            for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
                rand_num = random.randint(0, i)
                self.cards[i], self.cards[rand_num] = self.cards[rand_num], self.cards[i]
        class Card:
            def __init__(self, value, suit, img):
                self.value = value
                self.suit = suit
                self.img = img                
dealer = Dealer()
deck = dealer.Deck()
deck.shuffle()
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I found this myself this morning as I was changing the ridiculous shuffle method that didn't work!

Comment: Just an FYI @Milad, I would upvote, but I am too new to stackoverflow and don't have that ability yet! But I really do appreciate your answer. Thank you very much for your time!